# before_destroy definition NoMethodError

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, nomethoderror

hey I'm having a little trouble with this function

```ruby
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :group
end

class Group < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :users
  attr_accessible :name
  validates_presence_of :name

  before_destroy :set_default_group

  private
  def set_default_group
    self.users.each do |u| 
      puts u # prints out <User:0x007fd678a85cb8>
      u.group = self.first
      u.save    
    end
  end
end
```

it gives me this error NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for #Group id: 18, so what is wrong with my definition?

the error message

```
    NoMethodError: undefined method `group' for #<Group id: 18>
from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activemodel-3.2.8/lib/active_model/attribute_methods.rb:407:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/attribute_methods.rb:149:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/.../Developer/rails/.../app/models/group.rb:12:in `block in set_default_group'
    from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:89:in `each'
    from /Users/.../.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p194/gems/activerecord-3.2.8/lib/active_record/associations/collection_proxy.rb:89:in `method_missing'
    from /Users/.../Developer/rails/.../app/models/group.rb:10:in `set_default_group'
```

Comment: Maybe the `group` is a reserved keyword?

Comment: when I'm in Rails Console I can use u = Group.first and then u.group to print out the users group, so I dont think it's a reserved keyword

Comment: what about `u.group_id = Group.first.id` ?

Comment: In what context do you get the error, and can you edit your question to include the full error?

Comment: added full error message

Comment: Are you sure it's that `u.group` assignment causing the error? Your error message is saying `group` is being called on an instance of `Group` which does not occur in your private method. You should be able to provide more context as @TomHarrisonJr requested (like a line number or stack trace)

Comment: @daiikota there should be a stack trace indicating which file and on while line the exception has been raised. Please add this information to your question.

Comment: edited again, i hope this helps more

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error doesn't make sense, since you're calling *#group* on *user* and not on *group*.

However, I believe that

```
u.group = self.first
```

will not work as you intend it to, since *#first* is a class method, and *self* here is an instance. Try:

```
u.group = self.class.first
```

or simply:

```
u.group = Group.first
```

Comment: ok now I'm not getting the error message anymore, but it doesn't save the first group to every user in the old group, I did also try u.update_attributes(:group => Group.first)

Comment: in the console I have the right group set (first group), but the update is not reflected in the database

Comment: I'll think about what the issue could be, but technically your question is answered, so consider selecting this as the answer.

Comment: yes your answer is right, even the error message that I've got was totally wrong :) and I will also try to figure out why the changes are not reflected in the database, but that's another question